# cant include skript or variable in php

Tags: php

i have a simple skript that is sending the User to another Page if the input is over 10, from the other skript i want to echo the input. But it giving me the warning that: Warning: Undefined variable $QT
and anyhow it is also copying the whole page that i am including so the pages looking the same.

I tried with require and include and also to paste the whole location of the skript

Skript1:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" && $_POST["QT"] > 10) {
  $QT = $_POST["QT"];
  header("location: ../main/Skript2.php");
  die();
}
else{
  
}

?>
```

Skript 2:

```
<?php

include "Skript1.php";
echo $QT;
?>
```

Both skripts are in the same Folder main.

thanks for helping

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump() the POST outside of the conditional as a test to make certain the POST is making its way to your 2nd page and that 'QT' is in fact in the POST global?

Comment: @dalelandry yes its possible to var_dump the data outside of the condition

Comment: Have you tried if(!isset($QT)). Like if(!isset($QT)){
$QT = 'Variable name is not set';
}

Comment: @Csisanyi with !isset it respond so it should be that, but how can i fix that?

Comment: Honestly I tried to check your problem, but I have no php currently on my machine andI t ried with some visualstudiocode extension to set up a server, but I failed miserably to set my includepath correctly so far :D :With all that said, the error message says it all, QT is not set at the time when the page is called.
You need to make sure QT is set. Also seems a bit weird that you cross reference the pages.
Like you include 1 in 2 and you set a location to 2 in 1, but this is just a guess, I haven't used php in a while.

Comment: maybe try to set QT outside the condition, and call header on the condition your QT is set and  meets your condition of >10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use header location with a parameter.

Skript 1:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" && $_POST["QT"] > 10) {
  $QT = $_POST["QT"];
  header("location: ../main/Skript2.php/?number=$QT");
  die();
}
else{

}
?>
```

Skript 2:

```
<?php
$QT = $_GET['number'];
echo $QT;
?>
```

More than one variables can be joined to a string with a delimiter and then exploded.

Skript 1:

```
<?php
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" && $_POST["QT"] > 10) {
   $xy = "test";
   $QT = $_POST["QT"];
   $all = $QT.",". $xy;
   header("location: ../main/Skript2.php/?number=$all");
   die();
}
else{

}
?>
```

Skript 2:

```
<?php
$all = $_GET['number'];
$parts = explode(",", $all);
echo $parts[0]."<br>";
echo $parts[1]."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: nice using get parameter, You can also use session variable to get $QT anywhere!

Comment: @rauwitt is there a way to acess multiple variables with this method? i tried to just put again a /xyz= $var2 but this isnt working